# Launching options for Sencha Studio embedded Chrome browser

Tags: testing, extjs, acceptance-testing, headless-browser

I'm working with Sencha Studio / Sencha Test and everything works well. Strategically we want to execute our automated user acceptance tests in the most performant way, so the idea came up to use a headless browser.

I wonder whether it's possible to run Sencha Studio's embedded Chrome browser in "headless mode" via --headless? Is there a possibility in Sencha Studio and on command line via `stc` to launch that browser with some custom parameters?

And how about adding Sencha Cmd's PhantomJS to my locally available browsers? Would that be a reasonable alternative?

Comment: Not sure about your actual question, because I don't use Sencha Studio, but if you have Sencha Cmd installed as well, you have a "headless Chrome" on your hard drive, since Cmd comes with PhantomJS. I cannot check right now, but what I heard it is a standard build that you can use [with standard PhantomJS parameters](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I updated my question which now includes the usage of PhantomJS.

Comment: It should be possible to use PhatomJS with Sencha test and webdriver there are some mentions on the forums https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?331809-Can-t-find-PhantomJS-but-does-see-PhantomJS-using-Sencha-Test-2